# Missing argument for parameter #1 in call on a button

Tags: swift, swiftui

I used to have these rows defined in the list view itself, but now that I've broken the rows off into its own view I'm getting this vague error. Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

It tells me to Insert '<#LocalizedStringKey#>, ' to fix this but I'm not sure why it's needed or what I should put in as the Localized String Key.

```
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                List{
                    ForEach(result) { (log: Expenses) in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.editExpense = log
                            print(log.id)
                        }) {
                            HStack() {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                                    Text(log.nameText).padding(.horizontal, -7)
                                    Text(log.dateText).font(.caption).padding(.horizontal, -7)
                                }
                                Spacer()
                                VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 8){
                                    Text(log.amountText)
                                    Text(log.expenseAccount?.capitalized ?? "").font(.caption)
                                }
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                    .onDelete(perform: onDelete)
                }.padding(.horizontal, -20).navigationTitle("Expense List")
```

But now I have created a row view and want to call it for each item in Expenses. For some reason I'm getting the error at the line below.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
struct ExpenseList: View {
    
    @State var editExpense: Expenses?
    @State var addExpense = false
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext
    
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Expenses.expensesList)
    private var result: FetchedResults<Expenses>

    
    init(predicate: NSPredicate?, sortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Expenses>(entityName: Expenses.entity().name ?? "Expenses")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        if let predicate = predicate {
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        }
        _result = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
                List{
                    ForEach(result) { (log: Expenses) in
                        Button(action: {     <----- Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
                            self.editExpense = log
                        })
                        ExpenseRow(name: log.nameText, date: log.dateText, amount: log.amountText, account: log.expenseAccount ?? "")
                    }
                    
                    .onDelete(perform: onDelete)
                }.navigationTitle("Expense List")
```

ExpenseRow view in case it's needed

```
import SwiftUI


@available(iOS 14.0, *)
struct ExpenseRow: View {

    let name: String
    let date: String
    let amount: String
    let account: String
    
    
    var body: some View {

            HStack() {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                    Text(name).padding(.horizontal, -7)
                    Text(date).font(.caption).padding(.horizontal, -7)
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 8){
                    Text(amount)
                    Text(account.capitalized).font(.caption)
                }
                
            }
            
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's because you haven't defined what your button looks like.

Comment: You're exactly right @aheze! I added an empty string and the error went away. But I want the button to be the ExpenseRow view. I can't figure out how to do that, since it expects a string

Comment: It accepts any `View`, so just put `ExpenseRow` in place of the `Text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define what your button looks like, like this:

```
Button(action: {
    self.editExpense = log
}) {
    /// ↓ put `ExpenseRow` inside the brackets!
    ExpenseRow(name: log.nameText, date: log.dateText, amount: log.amountText, account: log.expenseAccount ?? "") 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realize that the button string could be replaced with a view using brackets. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score -1):

When I typed `Text("Start")` it went away:

```
Button(action: {
            print("Exit The Onboarding")
        }) {
            Text("Start")
        }
        }
```